# hyperledger composer sample networks not available

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Facing issues in fetching the sample Networks in Hyperledger composer playground editor. Am trying to create a sample network using the sample networks which was available in hyperledger composer online editor https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/editor.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlqSJ.png) Attaching the error screenshots as well.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfWer.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is currently due to a problem with failing searches on the npm registry. a fix is available in meantime on composer-playground unstable

Hosted here: https://composer-playground-unstable.mybluemix.net/

Or for local install with npm:

> npm install --global composer-playground@unstable

Comment: tried accessing the composer-playground-unstable version, but still landing in same error. "Error: could not get any sample networks."

Comment: It looks like NPM have fixed their search problems now. both composer-playground.mybluemix.net and composer-playground-unstable.mybluemix.net can now pull down the samples.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved automatically. I guess it was due to some site mainatainence.

Answer (score 0):

By default composer playground does not lauch the sample network. Can you click the card where it's written Deploy your new business network then composer play ground will launch the sample.